# Changing Account Ownership via Apex

Tags: apex, account, account-teams

Is it possible to have the account team recalculated **automatically** whenever the owner is changed via Apex?

I.e. remove the account team of the old owner and add the account team of the new owner.

Salesforce provides this functionality when this update occurs via the **UI**.
However, if I change the owner through **Apex code**, it will only add its team members without removing the team members of the old owner.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you done any research you can share?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have edited my question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson is there any way to achieve this without writing whole class to manipulate AccountTeamMember  and AccountShare objects ?

Comment: No, I believe you need `Apex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Trigger after update` on Account (if the owner change), and use update operation on `AccountTeamMember` object.

[This is link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm) to the official doc for `AccountTeamMember`.

**Edit:**

Here's an example :

the trigger may look to this:

```
Trigger AccountTrigger on Account(after update,...){
   AccountTriggerHandler accHandler = new AccountTriggerHandler();
   Map<Id, Account> accountsToProcess = new Map<Id, Account>();

   for(Account newAccount : Trigger.new){
       Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(newAccount.Id);

       if(oldAccount.ownerId != newAccount.OwnerId) {       // if The owner change

           accounts.put(oldAccount.Id, oldAccount);
           accHandler.processAccountTeamMembers(accountsToProcess);
       }
   }
}
```

The `AccountTriggerHandler` class it's just a Normal class that will handle your trigger(it forms part of best practices)

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {
// Here yous should do your processing with AccountTeamMembers
public void processAccountTeamMembers(List<Account> accounts) {
    Set<Id> accountsOwners = new Set<Id>();

    // first you get the onwers of the account
    for(Account acc : accounts.values()) {
        accountsOwners.add(acc.OwnerId);
    }

    // Then Select AccountTeamMembers for the accounts
    List<AccountTeamMember> accMembers = new List<AccountTeamMember>([Select Id, UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId IN :accounts.keySet() and UserId IN :accountsOwners]);

    // then you do the processing you want with the AccountTeamMembers
        ...
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need Help

**Note:**

to be able to work with `AccountTeamMember` object with Apex, the `API version`  of your class should be at least `37.0`

I hope this help you to resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks for replying. The only way to perform this is to write a code to manipulate the AccountTeamMember object ?

Comment: yes, with the trigger `after update` on Account(controlling if the owner change) will work, i'll edit my answer to give an example

Comment: Thanks a lot , I thought like Salesforce provides another way instead of creating a class to handle this scenario manually.

Comment: Well in your trigger you can do all the processing, but it's a good practice to have one trigger per object and one `ClassHandler` for your trigger